# Neural Network Multiple | Averging predictions

Tags: python, neural-network, prediction, ensemble-learning

I am training multiple neural networks with various parameters. I am trying to average their **predictions**, but I am not really sure what that means, I am confused about ***what*** to average exactly. Here is what I mean: For a single observation in binary classification for example, the final node will give `p` a value between 0 and 1 (or -1 and 1 if you're using hyperbolic tangent Activation Function), then this `p` will be rounded to 1 or 0 if it's > 0.5, depending on your decision boundary.

Now, here is what I don't understand, should average `p1`, `p2` and `p3` produced by the models before rounding, or I should round the values to **True/False** responses and then compute the average? and how does that work exactly ?

Comment: Can you specify the overview of the problem you are trying to solve...
Ie. Binary classification, multi class classification, multi label classification Looks you are trying for Ensembling of various networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could do. All of them are categorized under Ensemble methods in machine learning.

**Voting classifiers**: which is the simplest way. You just take votes based on the label from all models and uses the majority label. That means, you should first round up all labels to 0 or 1 and then use the majority.

**Weighted voting classifiers**: similar to previous one, but some models have higher weights in voting.

For more information look [here](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/classifier/EnsembleVoteClassifier/).

Comment: So what happens if I don't round up the values and used some majority function? I am just interested on the reasoning behind it if that's possible.

Comment: The reason is, if you have 100 models all are making a prediction between 0 and 1. In some cases, they might behave randomly and if you computes the average, the average may always converge to 0.5.

Comment: God I've been working on this project for months now and nothing made sense really  because I wasn't rounding :/